# Django : ModelForm Pre-populate Checkbox with Custom Query

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset, modelform

I am working on my first Django Project.

I have a Many-to-Many Relation between two models: User and Project. 
While Updating a Project, I want to show form with Add New members and remove Existing members field with correct Choices based on current Project Users.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Get the Current Project from URL
2. Pass the current Project to Model Form
3. In Form, run Custom queryset.

Problem: Not Displaying result of Query Set.

In views.py

class UpdateProject(LogInRequiredMixin, UpdateView):

```
""" Class to Edit Project.
"""

form_class = ProjectUpdateForm
template_name = 'project/create.html'

def get_object(self):
    self.project_instance = models.Project.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['project'])
        return self.project_instance

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(UpdateProject, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'project': self.project_instance})
    return kwargs
```

For forms 
ProjectUpDateForm

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Form to update Project Field. """

    add_member = forms.CharField(label="Add New Members", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    del_member = forms.CharField(label="Remove Members", widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project = kwargs.pop('project')
        super(ProjectUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print MyUser.objects.exclude(pk__in=self.project.members.all())
        print MyUser.objects.filter(pk__in=self.project.members.all())

        self.fields['add_member'].queryset = MyUser.objects.exclude(pk__in=self.project.members.all())
        self.fields['del_member'].queryset = MyUser.objects.filter(pk__in=self.project.members.all())

   # Rest of Class Logic
```

Print Statements are working and returning correct result, however I am unable to view the results in app. It is displaying blank.

Also, I want to know is their easier way to achieve the same? (Seems to me that I shouldn't have to pass project explicitly? )

Comment: What is your Meta class for both forms ?

Comment: @Pcriulan     

For Form
class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'description']

For View, I am not using Meta

Comment: Ok so you need to add your custom fields in fields : fields = ['title', 'description', 'add_member', 'del_member']. That way you're telling django to be aware of these fields.

Comment: Done that. Still No Improvement.

Comment: @Pcriulan To be clear, it is (and was) displaying both field names on Page, but is not displaying any options

Comment: Can you post your template ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for discussion. I was able to solve problem though. Template was just simple form.as_ul

Answer (score 2):

I understand the idea of adding `add_member` and `del_member` actions.

But why couldn't you just use a single `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to display every user that could be inside the project, and just check boxes to show users who already take part to the project?

I didn't test this, but it could look like :

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'description']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_members = self.instance.members.all() # What are the current members?
        possible_members = User.objects.all() # Change this if you want a different set of users to add.
        self.fields['members'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Members",
                                                                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                                                queryset=possible_members,
                                                                initial=current_members,
                                                                required=False) # If it can be empty

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)  # Saving with commit=False add a save_m2m method to self
        if commit:
            instance.members.clear()           # We delete every member
            for m in self.cleaned_data.get('members'): # We them add again every checked user as member at form submission
                instance.members.add(m)
            instance.save()                    # We save the instance
            self.save_m2m()                    # We also save the changes in the M2M relationship.
            return instance
```

The trick is retrieving the users being currently members of the project instance and precheck checkboxes to show them amongst the whole list of all users (checked : user who's a member, not checked : user who's not a member).

So if you check a box, you add the user, and if you uncheck it you remove it from members list.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could find out, this solves the problem

When adding Many-To-Many field explicitly in Model Form, and you expect Multiple response, the module used should be [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField)

Also, since we are over-riding init method, and have a queryset in it, the best place to define it is inside init.

Final Form Code:

```
class ProjectUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Form to update Project Field. """


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project = kwargs.pop('project')
        super(ProjectUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['add_member'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Add New members",
                                                                   widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                                                   queryset=MyUser.objects.exclude(pk__in=self.project.members.all()))
        self.fields['del_member'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="Remove Members",
                                                                   widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                                                   queryset=MyUser.objects.filter(pk__in=self.project.members.all()))

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'description']

   #Rest of Form Logic
```

And this should do it!

---

*May be useful to someone*

In case, we already have defined field in our model, we don't need to completely over-write it in *init* (if query requires passed parameters)

We can define it queryset in init by 
self.fields['field_name'].queryset = logic

And add widget in Meta class.

---

*PS: I am still searching for easier way to access current object rather than being explicitly passed by View though!*

Answer (score 0):

front page HTML code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="{{ customer.pk }}"></td>
```

backend views.py code:

```
models.Customer.objects.filter(pk__in=request.POST.getlist('checks[]')).update(consultant_id=None)
```

infact name='V'==getlist('V')   , didn't need []

## ===========

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="{{ customer.pk }}"></td>
```

models.Customer.objects.filter(pk__in=request.POST.getlist(''checks'))

Comment: name='arg'      getlist('arg')